# How to get html,css,js code from textarea and compile it

Tags: javascript, html, css

I get some code from my client in 3 separate  textarea for  html, css, js. I want to run that code with in a div elements. I can't find correct solutions. Please explain me or forward me if already have solutions.

Comment: update your question and specify your requirements clearly.if you have tried any code then upload it also

Comment: I think you did not understand. I'm not trying any code . Actually I can no idea how to do.  Input textarea I get some code from my client. And now how  run it.

Comment: do you want to create  a compiler for html css ?

Comment: Yes you got it. I get some code from my client and  and run it with in div elements

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Basic level  Compiler for HTML,CSS,JS

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>Web Editor</title>
<meta content='width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0, maximum-scale=1.0, user-scalable=0, shrink-to-fit=no' name='viewport' />
</head>

<style type="text/css">

.code-frm-scratch-tag-heading{
height: 10%;
border-top-left-radius:  5px;
border-top-right-radius: 5px;
width: 100%;
display: block;
text-align: center;
justify-content: center;

}
.code-frm-scratch-fd{
    width: 100%;
    height: 90%;
    background-color: #9a9a9a33;
    border-radius: 4px;
    border-top-left-radius: 0px;
}
[contentEditable=true]:empty:not(:focus):before{
        content:attr(data-text)
    }

</style>   
 <body >
        <table style="width: 100%;height:245px;">
            <tr>
                <td style="width: 33%;height: 100%;">

                    <div class="code-frm-scratch-tag-heading" >

                      <div style="background-color: #0067ff;height: 100%;width: 55px;color: white;border-top-right-radius: 5px;border-top-left-radius:5px;display: table;  ">HTML</div>
                     </div>
                    <div style="background-color: #9a9a9a33;height: 90%;padding: 2px;border-radius: 5px;border-top-left-radius: 0px;">
                    <div id="html" data-text="Enter html code  here" style="height:100%;overflow: auto;word-wrap: break-word;max-width: 496px;max-height: 212px;" class="content" spellcheck="false" contentEditable="true" ></div></div>



                </td>
                <td  style="width: 33%;height:100%;">

     <div class="code-frm-scratch-tag-heading" >

                      <div style="background-color: #0067ff;height: 100%;width: 55px;color: white;border-top-right-radius: 5px;border-top-left-radius:5px;display: table;  ">CSS</div>
                     </div>


                    <div style="margin-left: 1.5px;background-color: #9a9a9a33;height: 90%;padding: 2px;border-radius: 5px;border-top-left-radius: 0px;">
                    <div id="css" style="height:100%;overflow-y: scroll;word-wrap: break-word;"  data-text="Enter css code  here" class="content" spellcheck="false" contentEditable="true"></div></div>
                </td>
                <td style="width: 33%;height:100%;">



     <div style="height: 10%;border-top-left-radius:  5px;border-top-right-radius: 5px;width: 100%;display: block;text-align: center;justify-content: center;" >

                      <div style="background-color: #0067ff;height: 100%;width: 55px;color: white;border-top-right-radius: 5px;border-top-left-radius:5px;display: table;  ">JS</div>
                     </div>    


                    <div style="margin-left: 1.5px;background-color: #9a9a9a33;height: 90%;padding: 2px;border-radius: 5px;border-top-left-radius: 0px;">
                    <div id="js" style="height:100%;overflow-y: scroll;word-wrap: break-word;"  data-text="Enter js code  here" class="content" spellcheck="false"   contentEditable="true"></div></div>
                </td>
                </table>    


   <div style="width:100%;height: 8px; "></div>


     <table style="width: 100%;height: 245px;" >
                        <tr > <td style="height: 100%;">

     <div class="code-frm-scratch-tag-heading" >

                      <div  style="background-color: #0067ff;height: 100%;width: 78px;color: white;border-top-right-radius: 5px;border-top-left-radius:5px;display: table;  ">OUTPUT</div>
                     </div>


                    <iframe id="output" frameborder="0" class="code-frm-scratch-fd" ></iframe> </td> </tr>        
                </table>               

    </body>
</html>
<script>
window.onload=function(){
    var html=document.getElementById("html"),
        css=document.getElementById("css"),
        js=document.getElementById("js"),
        output=document.getElementById("output"),
        working=false,
        fill=function(){
            if(working){
                return false;
            }
            working=true;
            var document=output.contentDocument,
                style=document.createElement("style"),
                script=document.createElement("script");
            document.body.innerHTML=html.textContent;
            style.innerHTML=css.textContent.replace(/\s/g,"");
            script.innerHTML=js.textContent;
            document.body.appendChild(style);
            document.body.appendChild(script);
            working=false;
        };
    html.onkeyup=fill;
    css.onkeyup=fill;
    js.onkeyup=fill;
}
</script>
```

just copy the code and paste it in separate file. In 
html code -html code ,css -css code, js -js code.Just paste the below given code in respective code areas.

HTML:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>    
<p id="demo">Click the button to change the layout of this paragraph</p>    
<button onclick="myFunction()">Click Me!</button>    
</body>
</html>
```

css:

```
body{
background:red;
}
```

js:

```
function myFunction() {
  var x = document.getElementById("demo");
  x.style.fontSize = "25px"; 
  x.style.color = "red"; 
}
```